# Expected type 'str', got 'List[str]' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to create a text based adventure game in PyCharm, and the bit I'm coding now is when the player opens a set of drawers to look inside. I want them to know how many items are in the drawer they open, and what the items are; but I keep getting a message saying `Expected type 'str', got 'List[str]' instead`.

How do I fix this? The problem is right at the bottom of the code.

```
if "go to drawers" in choice:
    drawerStates = '1 and 2 are open. 3 is missing a handle.'
    drawer1Inventory = ['lipstick', 'cute photo of a dog', 'socks']
    drawer2Inventory = ['T-shirt', 'jeans', 'pants', 'socks']
    drawer3Inventory = ['key']
    subLocation = 'drawers'
    slowprint('You go to the set of drawers.')
    time.sleep(1)
    slowprint('''They're very old and worn down. Only 2 out of the 3 have handles.
     You need to find the third handle to open it.''')

    while subLocation == 'drawers':
        slowprint('What would you like to do? (Type help for help)')
        choice = input('>')
        if 'location' in choice:
            slowprint('You are at the ' + subLocation + ' in the ' + location)

        if 'help' in choice:
            slowprint('Right now drawers ' + drawerStates)
            slowprint('''Type 'open drawer 1' to open the 1st drawer.
            Type 'open drawer 2' to open the 2nd.
            Type 'open drawer 3' to open the 3rd''')

        if 'open drawer 1' in choice:
            slowprint('Currently, there are ' + len(drawer1Inventory) + 'items in this drawer.')
            slowprint('Items in drawer 1:' + drawer1Inventory)
```

Comment: When posting to SO, please include the full traceback.

Comment: Also, if the error is in `slowprint`, we need to know what that looks like too. My guess is that the error is in the last line when you add a list to a string. Instead, turn the list into a string by saying `",".join(drawer1Inventory)` which does exactly what it sounds like. It puts a comma between every element. In the future, your posts should be completely self-contained; anyone should be able to copy-paste your code into their editor to reproduce your error.

Comment: wdym when you say 'more self contained'?

Comment: Read [mcve]. I mentioned it in my other comments, but the entire traceback should be included so that readers can follow how the error is propagating and find the issue faster. Any dependencies should also be included (`slowprint`, in this example). This makes it **complete and reproducible**. If there is far too much code to include in one post, then remove irrelevant features until you come up with a **minimal** example that still demonstrates the problem. Usually, just doing that will help you solve the error yourself, anyways.

Comment: ok thanks u were very helpful

Answer (score 2):

In python, you cannot add strings and integers.

You should replace

```
slowprint('Currently, there are ' + len(drawer1Inventory) + 'items in this drawer.')
```

by:

```
slowprint(f'Currently, there are {len(drawer1Inventory)} items in this drawer.')
```

Moreover, you cannot add a string and a list, you should replace :

```
slowprint('Items in drawer 1:' + drawer1Inventory)
```

by:

```
slowprint(f'Items in drawer 1: {drawer1Inventory}')
```

(provided you are using python 3.6+)

Comment: That is one error, but not the cause of the error posted by the OP.

Comment: Thanks lol but im still having trouble with the very last line of my code

Answer (score 2):

drawer1Inventory is a list.  If you want it to print the items, try using join, this will take all the list items, and output a string, where each list item is separated by a comma:

```
slowprint('Items in drawer 1:' + ','.join(drawer1Inventory))
```